# Actions/Commands and events in Excel add-in

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-interop, excel-interop, excel-addins

I know Visual Studio has a Command system for creating custom keyboard shortcuts. Is there anything similar for Excel?

Is there a way to access the collection(s) of possible 'actions', including those that can be triggered by keyboard shortcuts or menu items? And if so, are there any events for detecting them?

The purpose of the add-in is to track excel feature usage, preferably including activation time and context, and whether or not the user activated it via keyboard or a menu.

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for in a bit more detail? Are you just looking to assign new shortcut keys or capture user input? I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: @JohnBustos I have edited the question to include a little more detail about the specific problem. Yes, I'm trying to capture user input. It would be nice to capture the command that was invoked, along with which keyboard shortcut or menu item was used to invoke it.

Comment: Probably simpler to hack into the Excel SQM data

Comment: @shader See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635463/i-have-a-vsto-application-as-an-add-in-to-ms-word-and-i-want-to-set-keyboard-sho/9840871#9840871